# VSCode Xdebug not stopping running process when stopping debugger (reason: Address is already in use)

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have been running Xdebug for years. About a week and a half ago it started to do something weird. In VSCode typically I would start the debugger, do my thing and then I would stop the debugger. Then later on I would simply start the debugger and do my thing and close it again. Never had an issue with this.

All of a sudden I can run the debugger for the first time with no issues. Then after I close it and I try to start it again I get

`Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Address already in use)`

At this point I have to find the running process on port 8000 and kill it. Restart VSCode and it runs again fine the first time.

I thought I must have done something so I completely uninstalled VSCode and reinstalled everything. I run my repos from a Docker container so I even uninstalled that and rebuilt everything. Still nothing.

Then I turned in my computer to IT and had them wipe the whole thing so I could start over from scratch. Reinstalled everything and same issue.

Then I had a mac that I use that had VSCode installed the same way that I have used many times and now the Mac is doing the same thing and I didn't touch it before that.

I am starting to think that there must have been a recent update with Xdebug that may have broken something. Anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: Please show what you are doing / your launch.json etc. This *"Failed to listen on localhost:8000"* has nothing to do with the Xdebug itself (since it uses different ports for communication), unless you are doing something completely wrong. So far (the situation in general) it looks like the PHP process (quite possibly PHP built in web server) is not getting terminated... And since you are using Docker for everything ... this means that it not supposed to be running that at all (on a local computer).

Comment: It would also help to check what PHP-related extensions you have installed in VS Code.